# Wait for ms after a statement execution objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, foundation

I have a BLE value set after which I need to wait for 6.25ms for other device to write into its buffer. 
so I have been using `usleep(6250)`... As I got to know `usleep` considers value in micro seconds... So I am considering 6250 `microseconds=6.25` ms. Is it the right api to use ? as there are different posts which say usleep should never be used in iOS etc. I am not able to make a difference in wait time by debugging it with breakpoint as I think the wait time is too less to be visible like I can with sleep(2)... Pls confirm if its right API to use and if I am passing right value to API. If not please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you shouldn't sleep a thread ever.   That blocks the thread and wastes system resources.

Instead, use `dispatch_after()` or a similar API.

As well, do you really need to wait at all?  Or does the device send some kind of acknowledgement that the write was successful?  I.e. is there some signal from the device that you can react to to know that the write happened?